How to open a chrome and close it in bat
I am trying to open a chrome page from cmd by open a .bat and close the newly opened page without affecting current open page.
I have came to following solution but all chrome page is affected. Is there a way to only close the google.com?
start chrome "http://www.google. com" 
timeout /t 3
taskkill /IM chrome.exe /F


You can command line open sites such as WWW.google.com and close each one by one (in reverse) using MS Edge.
It depends how your system calls MS edge here I just use start, but you could simpler use the "full quoted path"
>start msedge --app="http://www.google.com"
"C:\Program Files\Microsoft\Edge\Application\msedge.exe" --app="http://www.google.com".
NOTE you cannot set the Window Title nor size without other commands via say VBS or JScript.

Clearly If I call 3 times I get three apps

To close them individually I can use Taskkill 1 times each by name so here I have called 2 times.
>taskkill /FI "WINDOWTITLE eq google*" (note Case does not matter)

You may note the first time I ran it, that it did NOT respond. The problem was those "Windows" were not in focus (covered by my other MSEdge actions) e.g. easily masked by other apps.
